# How do I not repeat code when setting JLabel font and foreground over and over again

Tags: java, user-interface

I am wondering what the fastest way to setFont and foreground for JLabels would be because right now I find myself repeating the same code over and over again. Here is what I have and if anyone know how I could refine this I would greatly appreciate it!

```
        header.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
        header.setVerticalAlignment( JLabel.TOP );
        header.setFont( new Font( "Impact", Font.PLAIN, 40 ) );
        header.setForeground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        name.setFont( new Font( "Impact", Font.PLAIN, 20 ) );
        name.setForeground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        temperament.setFont( new Font( "Impact", Font.PLAIN, 20 ) );
        temperament.setForeground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        lifeSpan.setFont( new Font( "Impact", Font.PLAIN, 20 ) );
        lifeSpan.setForeground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        origin.setFont( new Font( "Impact", Font.PLAIN, 20 ) );
        origin.setForeground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        starHeader.setFont( new Font( "Impact", Font.PLAIN, 20 ) );
        starHeader.setForeground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        affectionStar.setFont( new Font( "Impact", Font.PLAIN, 20 ) );
        affectionStar.setForeground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        childStar.setFont( new Font( "Impact", Font.PLAIN, 20 ) );
        childStar.setForeground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        childStar.setFont( new Font( "Impact", Font.PLAIN, 20 ) );
        childStar.setForeground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        energyStar.setFont( new Font( "Impact", Font.PLAIN, 20 ) );
        energyStar.setForeground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        dogStar.setFont( new Font( "Impact", Font.PLAIN, 20 ) );
        dogStar.setForeground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        shedStar.setFont( new Font( "Impact", Font.PLAIN, 20 ) );
        shedStar.setForeground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        socialStar.setFont( new Font( "Impact", Font.PLAIN, 20 ) );
        socialStar.setForeground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        healthStar.setFont( new Font( "Impact", Font.PLAIN, 20 ) );
        healthStar.setForeground( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
```

Comment: Create a factor method that takes a reference to a `UILabel` and sets it accordingly. You may also want to look at [`UIAppearance`](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1625-uiappearance-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at this appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize a JLabel Array. It might go something like this (in whatever method...):

```
String[] labelNames = {"Header", "Name", "Temperament", "LifeSpan", "Origin",
                      "StarHeader", "AffectionStar", "ChildStar", "energyStar",
                      "DogStar", "ShedStar", "SocialStar", "HealthStar"};
java.awt.Color grayColor = java.awt.Color.LIGHT_GRAY; 
java.awt.Font font = new java.awt.Font( "Impact", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 20);
javax.swing.JLabel[] label = new javax.swing.JLabel[labelNames.length];

/* Demo Mouse Handler class for the label[] array
   if you decide you want a mouseListener for your
   JLabels                                      */
LabelslMouseHandler labelsMouseHandler = new LabelsMouseHandler();

for (int i = 0; i < labelNames.length; i++) {
    label[i] = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    label[i].setFont(font); 
    label[i].setForeground(grayColor);
    label[i].setName(labelNames[i]);
    /* If you want to apply common event handlers
       then you would do that here as well, for
       example....                            */
    label[i].addMouseListener(labelsMouseHandler); 
    
    // Add to panel component here with the desired 
    // set Layout manager...
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Inner Class - A Mouse Handler for ALL JLabels within the label[] array
private class LabelsMouseHandler extends java.awt.event.MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
         javax.swing.JLabel source = (javax.swing.JLabel) evt.getSource();
         String name = source.getName();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You clicked on the " + name + " JLabel",
                        "Mouse Click Event", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        // Do what you want for MouseEntered
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        // Do what you want for MouseExited
    }
}
```

By the way, in your listing you have set `childStar` label properties twice.